# graphviz nodes of different colors

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to create a directed graph with nodes of different filled colors. I have created a gv file like this:

```
digraph mentions {
  "A" -> "B"
  "A" -> "C"
  "B" -> "C"
  "B" -> "A"
  "A" [shape=circle, style=filled, fillcolor=red]
  "B" [shape=circle, style=filled, fillcolor=green]
  "C" [shape=circle, style=filled, fillcolor=purple]
}
```

And my command line argument is:

```
ccomps -zX#0-1000 testGraphCalls.gv | \
grep "-" | cat <(echo "digraph mentions {") - <(echo "}") | \
sfdp -Gbgcolor=white -Ecolor=blue \
-Nwidth=1 -Nheight=1 -Nfixedsize=true \
-Nlabel='' -Earrowsize=0.4 -Gsize=75 -Gratio=fill \
-Tpng > test.png
```

However, the nodes of my white circles outlined in black. Any ideas of how I can get the nodes to fill properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is all the stuff in your command? When you grep for "-" in your .dv file, grep won't print the three attribute lines.

Do you have the program `dot`, which you could use for a quick test of your graph file?

Comment: Running the command 'dot -Nlabel='' -Tpng -o test.png testGraphCalls.dot' gives me a graph that also is filled white.

Comment: nevermind, that works! I had taken out the 'shape=circle, style=filled,'. But with that in there on each line, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a .gv file, write your dependency code in a .dot file.

Use python profilers like graphviz, qcachegrind, etc. which automatically converts the .dot file to a calling tree.